# Auto mounting network share which is temporary offline

Tags: networking, mount, fstab, cifs, automounting

following problem: I have a server which needs to mount a windows network share in order to copy a file on it.
So I added the share in the `fstab` so that it will be mounted on startup.

```
 //192.168.1.xx/share   /mnt/networkshare   cifs    noperm,username=user,password=******    0   0
```

A script loops to copy the file on the share like that:

```
while [ true ]
  do
    if [ -f /path/to/the/file ]
    then
      mv /path/to/the/file /mnt/networkshare
    fi
done
```

The problem is, that the windows computer is shutting down at night at starts in the morning. First, during this time, the load on the server is 100% on one core due to the while [true] script. Second, sometimes the mount is not working anymore after the startup of the windows computer. (a crontab `* * * * * mount -a` runs to mount all again) The files do not get copied and the mount is not accessible on the server. It needs to be restarted.

How can I make sure that the mount is always there while the computer is on. Do I maybe need to somehow umount the share? I can umount it every night, but what if the windows computer gets restarted during the day? How can I pause the while [true] script if the mount is not there for lower cpu load on night?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check the mount before attempting to move:

```
df | grep "/mnt/networkshare" |grep -v grep >/dev/null; r=${?}
if [ ${r} -eq 0 ]
then
  mv /path/to/the/file /mnt/networkshare
fi
```

also, adding a `sleep` command in the process might mitigate your 100% CPU utilization problem. Hammering a process without a break is not a good approach.

Comment: I tried it. If I mount the share, shutdown the machine and call df the server is stuck with the command for a pretty long time. But what is the difference to the way right now. Why does sometimes the share not work at all anymore? Can you please explain r=${?}, what is ? for

Comment: variable `r` is the exit code of the grep command. exit code 0 (zero) means it was successful, i.e., share was mounted. But while it was mounted, someone shuts off the windows machine, then you are out of luck until either forcefully umount the share (if you can  of course) or wait for the connection to time out, which might be quite along while

Comment: Thanks! Can I somehow see how long the timeout is? will this work, because unmounting while the script is accessing the folder is problematical

Comment: There is a way to figure out the timeout but I really can not remember as it is kinda convoluted. But, if this windows server shutdown without notice is a common occurence, I strongly suggest using _autofs_ you can install it on your linux machine `yum install autofs` or `apt-get install autofs` and whatever dependencies it requires. I suggest that you see the PARAGRAPH 4 of this page https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares